# Is using static variables in Unity inefficient? [C#] [Android]

Tags: android, static

I don't know a lot of programming but basically I read somewhere that if you declare a variable like this:

```
public static int hi = 1;
```

Then you can acces it from another file using "file.hi". (I don't really know what static is but that's not the point).

I do check some things in one of my scripts and then acces the variables from another one, although I could do them directly in the other script, because I don't want to have a mess of code and want it to be more organized, but the question is, does this have a big impact on the efficiency of the code? I'm working with android, so I don't want to start doing things wrong and then have my game run slower.

Thanks for your time and sorry for any english mistakes, I hope you understood my problem ;)

Comment: Static just means the method or member variable in a class holds the same value across 0 or more instantiations. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but OOP concepts like static are an important thing to know.

Comment: Is it possible that the variable will change its value?

Comment: This question has no pupose without any knowledge on what static is. It should become clear if you know what the keyword does and how it effects your "efficency". Anyway the term "efficiency" is quite ambigious and can mean many different factors. What do mean in particular? Time? Memory? Usuablitly from a programming perspective?...